# Where are all my android dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I am encountering the following error when building my code...

> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (21.0.3) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

I know this is a *build.gradle* problem.  However I can't seem to see the conflict.  I have two Modules my main and a library.

This below my dependencies for the Main Module.

```
    dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    api 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
    implementation project(':Library')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'gridlayout-v7'
    }
}
```

And here are the dependencies for the library.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    api 'com.annimon:stream:1.1.9'
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    api 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.marcouberti.autofitbutton:android-auto-fit-button:0.1.1@aar'
    api 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

So my question is where else could a dependency be hiding?

**EDIT** Adding in the rest of the build file.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.id"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode = 3000002
        versionName "v3.00.02"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_HEARTBEAT", "true"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "LAUNCH_APP_AFTER_APK_UPDATE", "false"
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "HIDE_COMMON_LOGS", "true"
        buildConfigField "String", "FTP_MEDIA_FOLDER_PATH", "\"s2/media/\""
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "WIFI_ENABLED", "true"
    }
    buildTypes {
        // Rename the output files for all variants
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "S2-" + variant.properties.flavorName.replace("S2_", "").replace("orion", "") + "-UPDATE-" + variant.versionName + ".apk"
            }
        }

        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "@string/app_name"]
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "@string/app_name_debug"]
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '.debug'
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    api 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
    implementation project(':Library')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'gridlayout-v7'
    }
}
```

Comment: May you please show up your full `app/build.gradle` file?

Comment: It must be hiding in your dependencies. You need to check your dependency graph by `gradlew :<module-name>:dependencies`. Last time my issue was solved by updating `glide` to `4.7.1`

Comment: Added the rest of the build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being an issue when going from

> compileSdkVersion 26

to

> compileSdkVersion 27

for now just going back to 26.